# Python method returns none

Tags: python, function, methods, return, nonetype

I have a weird problem. I have a function that is supposed to returns list. I call the function using an object called 'common' and found that it returns None always (common.reset_this). But when I define this function outside the class, it returns what it is supposed to return.
Is there anything I am missing here.

```
class something_else():

    //
    ...

    //
    def reset_this(self,unit = 0):
        with self.__reset_lock:
            status = self.get_status(unit)
        return status
```

Comment: Is "common" a global variable?  How is "common" being bound to its underlying object?  Can you confirm that the "common" to which you're referring in this (method) code is identical to the "common" you're accessing in your function as defined outside of any class? Try the `id()` function on both (print or logging).  How about the "unit" that you're passing to .get_status()?

Comment: your method lacks a `self` in its signature if it is meant to be an `instance` method. Otherwise if it is a `static` method, you need to decorate it with `@staticmethod`. Otherwise, if it is a `class` method, you need to decorate it with `@classmethod` (and add the class to its signature)

Comment: corrected the typo - replaced common with self and added self as argument for the method.

Comment: Are you actually creating an instance of the "something_else" class and then calling the "reset_this" method on that instance?

Comment: @Brent Taylor : yeah something like that

Comment: @user2927392 "something like that".  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Brent Taylor: Yes that is what I am doing. common is an instance of the class something_else and I call the reset_this method from it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming it's not a typo you're missing the self argument to your method, you need:

```
class something_else():
    #
    # ...
    #
    def reset_this(self, unit = 0):
        with common.__reset_lock:
            status = common.get_status(unit)
        return status
```

Without it unit is getting passed the self object (as opposed to 0) because python doesn't care what you call it, the first argument is always the "self" object (the object the method is being called on).